# Disparity in rendering Malayalam glyph

Tags: linux, fonts, unicode, fontconfig

> Migrating from https://github.com/rsms/inter/issues/436

This is the correct rendering of the [word `prominence` in Malayalam](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=ml&text=prominence&op=translate). `പ്രാധാന്യം`. [image: പ്രാധാന്യം]

And this is how it renders on:

##### Arch Linux

| Where | Screenshot |
| --- | --- |
| [Whatsapp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/), Firefox | [image] |
| [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/) | [image] |
| [GNU Nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) | [image] |
| [VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) | [image] |
| [GitHub](https://github.com), Firefox | [image] |
| [p.ip.fi](https://p.ip.fi), Brave | [image] |

##### Elementary OS

[image]

#### Fedora Kinoite

[image]

##### Android - WhatsApp

[image]

##### Windows - Notepad

[image]

---

This might not be new, but having such disparity is a bit annoying. How can I fix it on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You already pointed at it in your tags: the rendering of text is primarily up to the font you use, and how the font rendering engine uses that font. (Your shell, i.e., what displays nano, will technically necessarily still look different from your browser, because it needs to use fixed width rendering. That's by principle.)

Different font rendering engines have different ways to deal e.g. with *ligatures*; to me this looks like

so, I think:

1. [image: ന്യ is, if you insert a space between these letters, ന് യ. Notice the combining character right of ന!]
2. with the same font, some engines render these combined letters the way you want, others don't. Again, fixed-width engines have no choice – the idea of "these are two characters that look very differently when combined" is incompatible with "I can correctly display these two characters separately", on a logical level. Separately, these letters are ന and യ. Na and ya are two letters, and virama (candrakkala) combination actually suppresses the inherent vowel. Now, if I force you to write these separately, then you're kind of in a bad situation - നയ is simply not the same thing as ന്യ, but the drawing of Ya depends on the previous symbols being "· + Virama sign".
   That's *exactly* what we're seeing in all things meant for source code editing / display.
   Is this a good solution? Don't know, it doesn't look like it; at least your shell rendering is bad. But: I'm not a linguist / linguistic typographist. Hell, I don't even understand a single language with a Brahmic script!
3. For the websites that do it wrong, they might be delivering their own, broken, font, or they might be intentionally *normalizing* Unicode to be made of independent characters, which then erase the combining mark. This is often done as a safety measure, or an interoperability measure. In the case of whatsapp web and github, I'd try to figure out where to report it as a bug.

Comment: Hi, I read this: [Modern text rendering with Linux: Overview](https://mrandri19.github.io/2019/07/24/modern-text-rendering-linux-overview.html), but it's still a bit hazy. You say, fixed width engine requires two or more characters to be rendered separately, isn't that what `monospace` font is for? But even having same font (and engine probably...) on terminal & editor does not explain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ2sx.png).

Comment: It'd be nice to have a switch which toggles this rendering behavior.

Comment: a font can't solve the dilemma that these two characters *separately* are different than *together*. But a fixed-width engine is *meant* to draw them *separately*.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e '.say for "പ്രാധാന്യം".comb.map(*.uniname);'
MALAYALAM LETTER PA
MALAYALAM LETTER RA
MALAYALAM LETTER DHA
MALAYALAM LETTER NA
MALAYALAM LETTER YA
```

You need a tool to start looking at individual glyphs. Raku might be helpful, since it supports Unicode out-of-the-box.

```perl
~$ raku -e '.say for "പ്രാധാന്യം".comb.map(*.uninames.raku);'
("MALAYALAM LETTER PA", "MALAYALAM SIGN VIRAMA").Seq
("MALAYALAM LETTER RA", "MALAYALAM VOWEL SIGN AA").Seq
("MALAYALAM LETTER DHA", "MALAYALAM VOWEL SIGN AA").Seq
("MALAYALAM LETTER NA", "MALAYALAM SIGN VIRAMA").Seq
```

Trying to 'round-trip' the characters:

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for "പ്രാധാന്യം".comb.map(*.uninames)>>.uniparse;'
പ ്
ര ാ
ധ ാ
ന ്
യ ം
```

Possibly the different programs you've examined have different Normalization schemes. See the link below for an overview.

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode
https://raku.org